# How to store WebRTC media and stream it live?

Tags: node.js, express, webrtc

I'm using nodejs and expressjs to host a webserver.
What I want to do:

Client1 and Client2 are on the website and the website is allowed to use their microphones.
All microphone live streams are in an array.
Then every client can see all the clients connected to the website and enable/disable their streams.

Client1 wants to hear Client2 and just enables the microphone stream and can hear Client2.
If Client2 enables the microphone stream from Client1, too, they can talk (because they hear each other)

--

Is that possible with nodejs / WebRTC? I really have no idea how to do this.

Comment: How is this different from any regular webrtc site like hangouts?

Comment: I just want this on my own server, so I can make an ingame voicechat for example.